# App keeps stopping when i press a button

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I have a save button that loads a dialog interface asking for a save name. When you click done it's supposed to created a sharedpreferences with some strings in it, but instead it just says unfortunately the program has stopped. How can i fix this? Oh and i just want to put it out there that i'm new to android. I'm learning all of this stuff as i make the app.

```
public void save(View view){

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(Calculate.this);
    View pView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Calculate.this);
    adb.setView(pView);

    final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrompt);

    adb.setCancelable(false);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            n = name.getText().toString();
            try {
                details = getSharedPreferences(n,MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = details.edit();
                editor.putString("ebp", ebp.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("fb", fb.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("sv", sv.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("pv", pv.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("sl", sl.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("cl", cl.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });

    AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
    ad.show();


}
```

Logcat

```
05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575): java.lang.NullPointerException

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at                   com.TBJsoft.enclosurecalculator.Calculate$1.onClick(Calculate.java:103)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

05-18 20:54:28.300: E/AndroidRuntime(16575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your `Activities context` to access the `SharedPreferences` inside your `AlertDialog`. So you can either initialize them outside of the `AlertDialog` or change it to

```
   details =  Caluclate.this.getSharedPreferences(n,MODE_PRIVATE);  // assuming that Calculate is the name of your `Activity`
```

If this doesn't help then please post logcat so we know where its crashing

**Edit**

Change

```
final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrompt);
```

to

```
final EditText name = (EditText) pView.findViewById(R.id.etPrompt);
```

Comment: Hey, i tried to add the Calcualte.this and it didnt't work, but i posted the logcat. I only posted the ones that were red though.

Comment: It's this...n = name.getText().toString();

Comment: Then `name` is `null`. It must not be in `pView` or is spelled incorrectly

Comment: Yeah it has to do with the name. I deleted the layout inflater and alertdialog stuff. I just had save(View view) make the sharedpreferences stuff and when i clicked save this time i didn't get any errors. Is there another way i can have the person name the sharedpreference, and how do i know if it's being saved?

Comment: You can use what you had. Just create an `EditText` with `android:id'="@+id/etPrompt"` inside your `R.layout.prompt` layout

Comment: See my edited answer. You need to tell it to look inside the `inflated layout`

Comment: Well it didn't give me an error when i clicked save so i'm guessing it's saving. Thanks man.

Comment: To test if it saved, you could open the `SharedPreference`, get the `String` value, and display it in a `Toast` or a `Log`